# MimeMessage empty when using telnet?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I create a javamail MimeMessage from a inputstream:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, data);
Object content = message.getContent();
log.debug("content: "+content);
```

When i use thunderbird to send the email the content object contains the email text.

But when i use telnet to send email the content object is empty.

```
220 192.168.2.3 ESMTP SubEthaSMTP 3.1.7
mail from:test@test.com
250 Ok
rcpt to:burb@burb.com
250 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
test1
test2
test3
.
250 Ok
quit
221 Bye


Connection to host lost.
```

I do however can get content by manually reading the inputstream:

```
public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Is it possible to detect when to use the MimeMessage and when to use convertStreamToString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending the mail correctly through SMTP. The message data is usually a set of key/value pairs, followed by a newline, followed by the content. The reason your message is saying that there's no content is that your data is appearing to be all headers.

Your telnet session should look like:

```
220 192.168.2.3 ESMTP SubEthaSMTP 3.1.7
mail from:test@test.com
250 Ok
rcpt to:burb@burb.com
250 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
From: Test <test@test.com>
To: Burb <burb@burb.com>
Subject: My fantastic message

test1
test2
test3
.
250 Ok
quit
221 Bye
```

Comment: Cheers @AlBlue, i appear to be a bit rusty when i comes to telnet mail commands. I just gave it a shot with adding mail headers in the data section and it immediately worked!